# Не работает Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, x86-64

При установке Visual Studio Community (которая бесплатная) появляется ошибка "сбой пакета" у NuGet, Connected Services и пр (скриншот прилагается). При попытке запуска пишет об ошибке при запуске приложения (0xc000007b), скриншот тоже есть. Windows 7, x64, свежеустановленный.

[image: Скриншот установщика]

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/271809/ Похоже на описанную здесь проблему.

Comment: @shmeleva нет, не мой случай, но все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Простые варианты решения проблемы:

1. Отключить антивирусы
2. Отключить EDP
3. Запустить в режиме совместимости с другой платформой и правами администратор
4. Удалить и установить другую версию приложения

Comment: Нет, не подошло